# In Javascript, upon passing a declared class as an argument to Object.getPrototypeOf, the result refers to the parent class. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

For instance :

```
class Parent {

  foo() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {

  bar() {
    console.log("bar");
  }
}
```

Here, the expression

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Child) === Parent
```

would evaluate to true.

Now I understand the basics of prototypical inheritance and how classes work in Javascript that is, every function has a `prototype` property, which is copied on to the newly created class instance's `__proto__` property upon calling the function with the `new` operator

I also understand that `Object.getPrototypeOf` essentially returns the `__proto__` property of any given object and generally we simulate inheritance in pure javascript by the means of setting the `prototype` property of the child class to an instance of the parent class, like this :

```
function Parent(){}
 
Parent.prototype.foo = function(){
  console.log("foo");
}
 
function Child(){}
 
// Inherit properties from Parent
Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

My questions are :

- what does the result of `Object.getPrototypeOf` when called with a class as an argument represent ? How is it linked to class inheritance in TS/JS ?
- Is it safe to use `Object.getPrototypeOf` to check if whether a particular class extends another class at runtime ?

Comment: TypeScript is not involved. Everything in your question is JavaScript.

Comment: FYI, the child class constructor inherits from the parent class constructor so that *static class methods* are inherited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `extends` keyword does two things:

- It sets the SuperClass.prototype object as the prototype of the SubClass.prototype object. In your case, `Child.prototype` gets `Parent.prototype` object as its prototype.
- It also sets the super class' constructor as the prototype of the child class constructor. In your case, `Child` constructor gets `Parent` constructors as its prototype.

Above two statements essentially mean the following in code:

```js
class Parent {}
class Child extends Parent {}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Child.prototype) === Parent.prototype);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Child) === Parent);
```

In other words, the `extends` keyword sets up two prototype chains:

```
Child.prototype ---> Parent.prototype ---> Object.prototype

Child ---> Parent ---> Function.prototype ---> Object.prototype
```

So, `Object.getPrototypeOf(Child)` simply returns the `Parent` constructor.

Comment: To be more precise (and what your code also reveals), `Child.prototype` does not equal `Parent.prototype` (which is what your text implies). Rather it's `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)`.

Comment: @FelixKling If you are referring to `Child.prototype ---> Parent.prototype`, then I didn't mean to say that `Child.prototype` actually refers to `Parent.prototype`. What I actually meant was _Child.prototype inherits from (or is linked to) Parent.prototype_.

Comment: "It also sets the super class' constructor as the prototype of the child class constructor. In your case, Child constructor gets Parent constructors as its prototype"@FelixKling, Yousaf is there a specific reason why this happens , wouldn't the first part, that is "Child.prototype ---> Parent.prototype ---> Object.prototype" suffice as far as simulating inheritance is concerned ?

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you meant.

Comment: @KiranYallabandi See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72801799/in-javascript-upon-passing-a-declared-class-as-an-argument-to-object-getprototy/72801935?noredirect=1#comment128590048_72801799) by Felix.